# Python WordCloud - How to make the word colour based on a data column

Tags: python, csv, cloud

I have a list of film titles that I want on a Word Cloud, but the colours of the films depending on the film category (e.g. Drama, Comedy etc.) rather than completely random.

The data is in the form of a CSV, one column 'title' the other 'category'. I have the following code so far. I feel like I need to use the argument "color_func", but am not sure how.

```
#Importing Libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from wordcloud import WordCloud
from collections import Counter

#Importing Dataset
df = pd.read_csv("films.csv")

#Creating the text variable
word_ls = df.title

#Creating a count (I want the words to be the same size)
word_could_dict = Counter(word_ls)

# Creating word_cloud with text as argument in .generate() method
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(word_could_dict)

# Display the generated Word Cloud
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Optional extra questions:

1. Can I also have the font be randomly chosen, based on the film category?
2. How can I add a legend?

Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: There is an [example](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/colored_by_group.py) in the github repo that shows how to map colors based on category.

Comment: I've seen this, but I'll be honest it really goes a bit over my head.  I see "color_to_words" but these require manual definition for particular words, whereas I want to define by whether a title falls into a particular categories.  Do you have any advice on how to adapt that part of the code?

Comment: What exactly do you want to count? Your current example counts the titles, not the words in the titles. Do you mean to count the number of duplicate titles in the dataset? Or do you want to count the frequency of words in the titles? You could split the titles into words, but then the relationship with the categories is lost...

Comment: What I want is as an extra line of code to say: film <titles> within the same genre <category> should have the same colour. Ignore the count -- this might just be an error on my part, I thought that was being used to ensure that the words were scaled in accordance to their frequency (in which case I want it to be 1 i.e. all the same size)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have adapted your code to include the sample [color mapping](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/blob/master/examples/colored_by_group.py) code. As mentioned, your code doesn't do a word count, but a count of full titles (apparently `wordcloud` randomizes the size of the titles a bit if their frequencies are all the same to make the words fit the image; in the example below Mamma Mia! and Gnomeo and Juliet feature twice, the other films once):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from wordcloud import (WordCloud, get_single_color_func)
from collections import Counter
import random

#get sample dataset
df = pd.read_csv('https://gist.github.com/tiangechen/b68782efa49a16edaf07dc2cdaa855ea/raw/0c794a9717f18b094eabab2cd6a6b9a226903577/movies.csv')

#random color generation function
def random_color():
    return "#"+''.join([random.choice('ABCDEF0123456789') for i in range(6)])

#generate same random colors for each category
df['color'] = df.groupby('Genre')['Genre'].transform(lambda x: random_color())


class SimpleGroupedColorFunc(object):
    """Create a color function object which assigns EXACT colors
       to certain words based on the color to words mapping
       Parameters
       ----------
       color_to_words : dict(str -> list(str))
         A dictionary that maps a color to the list of words.
       default_color : str
         Color that will be assigned to a word that's not a member
         of any value from color_to_words.
    """

    def __init__(self, color_to_words, default_color):
        self.word_to_color = {word: color
                              for (color, words) in color_to_words.items()
                              for word in words}

        self.default_color = default_color

    def __call__(self, word, **kwargs):
        return self.word_to_color.get(word, self.default_color)

#create a dict of colors and matching movies
color_to_words = df.groupby('color')['Film'].agg(list).to_dict()

#Creating the text variable
word_ls = df.Film

#Creating a count (I want the words to be the same size)
word_could_dict = Counter(word_ls)

# Creating word_cloud with text as argument in .generate() method
wordcloud = WordCloud().generate_from_frequencies(word_could_dict)

# Words that are not in any of the color_to_words values
# will be colored with a grey single color function
default_color = 'grey'

# Create a color function with single tone
grouped_color_func = SimpleGroupedColorFunc(color_to_words, default_color)

# Apply our color function
wordcloud.recolor(color_func=grouped_color_func)

# Display the generated Word Cloud
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

To [add a legend](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists):

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

categories = df.groupby('color')['Genre'].agg('first').to_dict()
patches = [mpatches.Patch(color=k, label=v) for k,v in categories.items()]

plt.legend(handles=patches)
plt.axis("off")
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This is amazing, and exactly what I was after. Do you know if it's possible to add a legend to the chart?

Comment: @TheFriendlyAsker sure,  I've added an example in the answer. You can fiddle with marplotlib's plt.legend() to set the position etc. of the legend

Comment: Honestly you’re a legend. I massively appreciate your help on this. Thanks again!